# Modifying page contents returned by urllib2.urlopen

Tags: python, urllib2

I have a simple functioning Python proxy:

```
import SocketServer, SimpleHTTPServer, urllib, re

PORT = 80

class Proxy(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        page = urllib.urlopen(self.path)
        self.copyfile(page, self.wfile)

httpd = SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer(('', PORT), Proxy)
print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

This works as expected. But I'm having a problem with the `urlopen` return type.

If I modify the class as such:

```
class Proxy(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        page = urllib.urlopen(self.path)
        print page.read()                      # NEW LINE
        self.copyfile(page, self.wfile)
```

I can successfully print the html contents of the page but then `page` is empty (a void gets forwarded to the client).

I don't understand why `.read()` would empty the `file-type object`.

To get around this I tried re-writing the contents:

```
content = page.read()
print page.read()
page.write(content)
```

But apparently this file-type object doesn't have a `write` method.

**How can I read/write to this file-type object and still return a valid page to my client?**

Answer (score 1):

The `read` method on files objects can be called with some integer and it will read (and advance the pointer) that many bytes. What `read` does without argument is read data until EOF. If you did `file.tell` you'd see that it is now pointing at a place that many bytes into the file. If you want to reset your file you can do `file.seek(0)`. A better design though might be to have something like:

```
data = file.read()
print data
self.copyfile(data, self.wfile)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! Any ideas on how I can write to the file? For example a forbidden site I would just like to return "You can't see this".

Comment: Actually it turns out your method is not work. There is no seek method in that object and your other solution has the same problem. Data is then empty.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is, once `page.read()` from urllib.urlopen completes, `self.copyfile(page, self.wfile)` is no longer listening for new input to write to `self.wfile`.

What you need to do, is write your data to `self.wfile` directly and not try to piggyback/redirect another IO stream.

So, instead of:

```
content = page.read()
print page.read()
page.write(content)
```

You want:

```
content = page.read()
print page.read()
self.wfile.write(content)
```